# Vue JS navbar unwanted transition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I made a navbar that has absolute positioning, and added a fade-out transition to the `<router-view>`, but when the view is transitioned in, the navbar has a weird, mistimed fade out transition too. Why is an element that is outside of the `<transition>` wrapper being transitioned, and how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <ol class="navbar">
            <nav class="active-slider-holder">
                <router-link @click.native="activeElement1" to="/">Rooms</router-link>
                <router-link @click.native="activeElement2" to="ss">People</router-link>
                <router-link @click.native="activeElement3" to="ww">About</router-link>
                <div id="active-slider"></div>
            </nav>
        </ol>

        <transition name="fade-out" appear>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </transition>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you add your CSS to the question? It should probably look something like this:  
  ```.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's almost exactly that: 
.fade-out-enter-active,.fade-out-leave-active { transition: all 1.5s; }
.fade-out-enter, .fade-out-leave-to { opacity: 0; }

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding a `z-index` to my navbar element ¯\_(ツ)_/¯